# Enterprise Library creating multiple log files

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I'm studying the EntLib 6 logging block and on a simple flat file logging test I'm getting multiple log files. Here is what I mean :

This is the simple C# code

```
var logger = new LogWriterFactory().Create();

if (logger.IsLoggingEnabled())
{
     logger.Write("First message");
     logger.Write("Second message");
}
```

When I run my app for the first time, the TRACE.LOG file is created correctly. But when I run it a few more times.. this is what happens :

```
df13a7b0-3de6-4abd-8ccc-b1a5b7bc4b68trace.log
6a1134e2-c1d2-4dc5-98c6-63827b5ec00ctrace.log
813a8b81-bc7f-4730-8b9a-2452830f49a1trace.log
d4d2a3dc-ad4c-47bc-a15a-36ad694bb120trace.log
trace.log
```

multiple files are created

Comment: Are you running your program multiple times all at once, or running it once, closing and running it again?

Comment: See the answer from EntLib tech support here: https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/447205